# Populate DropDown using array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to populate a dropdown with some data i get from a SOAP server. The server provides me an array of the companies.

How would i use it to populate the DD ?

Here is my User class:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Unidades { get; set; }
}
```

Here is where i receive the companies and send it to the view, i get it from another `Action` that is redirecting to this `Action`:

```
var usuario = TempData["objUsuario"] as UsuarioSSO;

if (usuario == null) return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");

if (usuario.UsuarioUnidades == null)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuário não possui unidades");

    return View();
}

var model = new Models.Usuario
{
    Unidades = usuario.UsuarioUnidades.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.CodigoEmitente.ToString(),
        Text = x.NomeFantasia
    })
};

return View(model);
```

Here is how i'm trying to display it:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Unidades, new SelectList(Model.Unidades))
```

I have already tried of everything but it won't work, i get some conversion errors and when i can make it work it won't display the content, it will only display the object inside the `Text` area

```
System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem
```

Comment: I can't really undestand what "won't work" from your description, but the main problem I see if that you have not ogt a property on your model for the selected value. Once you have then the syntax is `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedUnidadeId, new SelectList(Model.Unidades))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have one property for the selected item and the list of available items, e.g.:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string Unidade { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Unidades { get; set; }
}
```

and then create the drop-down like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Unidade, Model.Unidades)
```

You can directly supply the `Unidades` as it is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

P.S.: I guessed the singular of `Unidades` as I do not speak your langauge, whatever it is. I recommend to ALWAYS use english in source code.

Comment: Thanks buddy, worked like a charm ! Sorry about the language thing and by the way u guessed right.

Just one question, this DD is inside a form that will be posted to my Action but i'm getting a invalid modelstate

Comment: What error do you get exactly (update your question)?

Answer (score 4):

Your model needs a value type property to bind the selected option to. If `CodigoEmitente`is typeof `int` then you model property needs to be

```
public int SelectedUnidades { get; set; }
```

and you need to assign the `SelectList` to another property in your view model or to a `ViewBag` property

```
ViewBag.UnidadesList = new SelectList(usuario.UsuarioUnidades, "CodigoEmitente", "NomeFantasia");
```

Then in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedUnidades, (SelectList)ViewBag.UnidadesList)
```